# PHP if else ignores after "OR/||" Operator

Tags: php, comparison-operators

Hi I'm having a problem with this line of code.

```
if($_SESSION['permission'] !=  "superadmin" || "admin"){
    //header("location:logout.php");
    echo $_SESSION['permission'];
}
```

It is a quick line that would logout the user if the access level is not **superadmin** or  **admin** but my if else is ignoring the "admin" after the || operator. Would appreciate any help on what could I be doing wrong. Thanks. Also tried && and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just fix your if to the following :

```
if($_SESSION['permission'] !=  "superadmin" &&  $_SESSION['permission'] != "admin"){
```

in your code you have two conditions

```
$_SESSION['permission'] !=  "superadmin" || "admin"
```

and this is interpreted like :

```
$_SESSION['permission'] !=  "superadmin"
OR 
"admin"
```

and the condition

```
 "admin"
```

is equvilant to true because its none empty value so it will always pass the if statment

Comment: Thanks big time. Works fine thanks again. learned a lot from this.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code :

```
if($_SESSION['permission'] !=  "superadmin" && 
$_SESSION['permission'] !=  "admin" 
){
             //header("location:logout.php");
             echo $_SESSION['permission'];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    if(($_SESSION['permission'] !=  'superadmin') && ($_SESSION['permission'] != 'admin'))   
     {
         //header("location:logout.php");
         echo $_SESSION['permission'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP use "short-circuit" for `OR` (even for `AND`, and other logical operator) statement.
That means - in case of `OR` operator - that if first condition is `TRUE`, second isn't evaluated.
Moreover, I'm not sure that your syntax is "good"; that's because (regardless short-circuit) first two strings will be compared (and the result will be `"superadmin"`; this is because two string are two `true` value, since they have a value and aren't `null`) and, then, this value will be compared with your session variable

Take a look on [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

If you want to rewrite it correctly, you have to do something like this

```
if($_SESSION['permission'] != "superadmin" && $_SESSION['permission'] != "admin")
{
  //do something
}
```